# Creating a search input with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am attempting to create a search form, the search is performed on third party site so there is no model just a controller.  I have it set up as follows

`views/items/index.html.haml` :

```
= search_field :search, :search_input
= submit_tag 'Search'
```

`views/items/search.html.haml`:

```
-@items.each do |item|
  %h1= item.title
```

`controllers/items_controller.rb`:

```
def index
   #I am unsure of what to put in here?  I think
   #I need something wich sends @search_input to my search method
end

def search
   @items = some_third_party_search_method_i_wrote{ params[:search_input]}
end
```

How does one properly use the `params` object in rails?  I don't understand how to get from the `index` page containing the search form to the `search` page containing the results of the search input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `search_field_tag` instead since your form isn't tied to a model/object:

```
= search_field_tag :search_input
```

Then `params[:search_input]` should work.